# RxJs mousedrag complete callback

Tags: coffeescript, easeljs, rxjs

I've been playing around with RxJs trying to replace the mouse event listeners on a canvas based whiteboard. I have drawing working great but for some reason the **completed** function never gets called.

It's pretty simple and based on the mouse event example in RxJs docs. Here's an extract of the code, you can see the full version here http://codepen.io/hanloong/pen/YyvqgM?editors=001

```
  point = (start, prev, current) ->
    start:      {x: start.offsetX, y: start.offsetY}
    previous:   {x: prev.offsetX, y: prev.offsetY}
    current:    {x: current.offsetX, y: current.offsetY}

  mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup')
  mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
  mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousedown')

  mousedrag = mousedown.flatMap (start) ->
    mousemove.zip mousemove.skip(1), (prev, current) ->
      point(start, prev, current)
    .takeUntil mouseup

  liveDraw = Rx.Observer.create(
    (pos) ->
      console.log pos
      # drawLine stage, shape, pos.previous, pos.current
    , (err) ->
      console.log "Error: #{err}"
    , () ->
      # never gets run
      console.log 'Complete'
  )

  mousedrag.subscribe liveDraw
```

The goal is to send the complete path to the server once the users finishes drawing which would ideally happen in the completed callback. Also is it possible to retrieve the entire collection at this point or should I be building another array as the events come in?

Comment: You can maybe try something like in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225810/rxjs-draw-line-on-html5-canvas?rq=1. Alternatively, you can try to debug to see what's going on. Cf: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/testing.md

Comment: Are you trying to call `takeUntil` on the `mousedrag` observable or on the zipped observable in your call to `flatMap`? Its not terribly clear in your coffeescript (a look at the output js shows its attached currently to the observable created by the call to `mousemove.zip`).

Comment: The `takeUntil` is on `zip`. The complete callback does get called if I move that to be on `mousedrag` but the downside to that is I would have to create a new subscription after every mouse drag completed (As far as I can tell).

Comment: Did you have a look at the answer in the first link I provided you with, in particular the use of the `repeat` operator to resubscribe to the `mousedown`?

Comment: Yes I did thanks, adding `repeat()` worked a treat. Just considering what method to collect the entire mouse drag path on complete.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are subscribing to an Observable (`mouseMove`) that will never complete. The `flatMap` operator will swallow all the intermediate `onCompleted` events that are being generated when you lift the mouse button.

I would suggest that you perform the drawing as a side effect, then gather all the events into an array and send them at the end. Apologies I don't use coffeescript so this is in ES6:

```
var mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousedown');

var mousedrag = mousedown.flatMap(start => {
                  return mousemove
                           //Pair up the events
                           .pairwise()
                           .takeUntil(mouseup)
                           //Draw each event as you receive it
                           .tap(p => drawLine(stage, shape, pos[0], pos[1]))
                           //Gather all the events from this drag
                           .toArray();
                });

//Subscribe will now receive arrays for each drag that has occured
mousedrag.subscribe(sendDataToServer,
                    err => `Error: ${err}`);
```

To use the `pairwise` operator you will need to include the `rx.lite.coincidence.compat.js` file as well.

Comment: Thanks paulpdaniels, I'll give that a try. Logic seems solid